# MPI kill unwanted processes

Tags: c, mpi

I'm using OpenMPI with C bindings.  In my code, there is a required number of processes.  If MPI is executed such that more processes are opened than are required, I wish to kill or terminate the extra processes.  How can I do that?

When I try to do that several ways I can think of, I get the following error:

```
mpirun has exited due to process rank 3 with PID 24388 on
node pc15-373 exiting without calling "finalize". This may
have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have much to add to what High Performance Mark has already written except the following. You can actually call `MPI_FINALIZE` and exit processes that come in excess but you have to be aware of the fact that this will disrupt all further collective operations on the world communicator `MPI_COMM_WORLD` - most of them would simply not complete (with `MPI_BARRIER` being the one that would certainly hang). To prevent this you might want to first create a new communicator that excludes all unnecessary processes:

```c
int rank, size;    
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

// Obtain the group of processes in the world communicator
MPI_Group world_group;
MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_group);

// Remove all unnecessary ranks
MPI_Group new_group;
int ranges[3] = { process_limit, size-1, 1 };
MPI_Group_range_excl(world_group, 1, ranges, &new_group);

// Create a new communicator
MPI_Comm newworld;
MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, &newworld);

if (newworld == MPI_COMM_NULL)
{
   // Bye bye cruel world
   MPI_Finalize();
   exit(0);
}

// From now on use newworld instead of MPI_COMM_WORLD
```

This code first obtains the group of processes in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and then creates a new group that excludes all processes from `process_limit` onwards. Then it creates a new communicator from the new process group. The `MPI_COMM_CREATE` operation would return `MPI_COMM_NULL` in these processes that are not part of the new group and this fact is used to terminate such processes. Given the fact that after this point some of the processes would have "disappeared" from `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, it is no longer usable for collective operations like broadcasts, barriers, etc. and `newworld` should be used instead.

Also, as Mark has pointed, on some architectures the extra processes might actually linger around even after they have returned from `main`. For example on Blue Gene, or Cray, or any other system that uses hardware partitions to manage MPI jobs, the additional resources would not be freed until the whole MPI job has finished. This would also be the case if the program is being run on a cluster or other system under the control of a resource manager (e.g. SGE, LSF, Torque, PBS, SLURM, etc.).

My usual approach to such cases is very pragmatic:

```c
int size, rank;

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
if (size != process_limit)
{
   if (rank == 0)
      printf("Please run this program with %d MPI processes\n", process_limit);
   MPI_Finalize();
   exit(1);
}
```

You could also use `MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);` instead of `MPI_Finalize()` to annoy the user :)

You can also use the process spawning features of MPI, but this would made the code more complex as you would have to deal with intercommunicators.

Comment: Thanks, to both you and HP Mark, for the helpful comments.  I ended up simply allowing the extra processes to finalize and return from main.  This frees resources on my desktop, but, of course, that's not a good indicator of how it would perform in a "real" environment.  I'll submit my job (using LSF on the IBM Bladecenter I'm using) and see what happens.  However, your highly pragmatic approach might be just the ticket, especially since in my case I always know beforehand how many processes to spawn and only I will be running the code.

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps an extended comment rather than an answer, but until Hristo Iliev comes along this might help ...

I'm not sure that you can do what you want.  I believe that if you try to kill an MPI process using non-MPI functionality (such as a Linux `kill`) then the MPI run time will crash because one of its processes has quit unexpectedly.  The error message you report tends to support my thinking.

You could call `MPI_FINALIZE` on the unwanted processes, but note that the MPI standards do not require that the underlying operating system processes (or threads or whatever) actually stop.  The call to `MPI_FINALIZE` finishes pending MPI operations and prevents further calls to (almost all) MPI functions on that process.  This may not be what you want either.  I suppose you might get lucky `kill`ing an already-finalised process, the MPI run time might not crash; this isn't something I've ever tried.

You could take a different approach and use MPI's capabilities to *spawn* new processes; start the program on one process, then spawn the number your program uses with calls to `MPI_SPAWN_PROCESS` and its relations.  You'll need to investigate, in addition to the MPI routines, how the spawning interacts with your platform's process management.  You might find that your system is not configured to permit dynamic process management by running MPI jobs.

Comment: Thanks, HP Mark.  I just started learning MPI the day before yesterday, and it's wonderful to hear from folks who obviously have a great deal of experience.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

> kill mpiexec.exe

on Windows, and all connected processes (mpiexec.exe, PMI proxy.exe, IMB MPI1.exe) will be terminated.