# Kill/Stop one process with MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, pthreads, mpi, openmp, openmpi

in order to achieve a parallel resilient code to solve large linear system, i have to simulate MPI failures, the idea is to kill or stop a rand process while its working , once i achieve this step, i'll start applicating other techniques for fault mitigation.

in order to kill a process, i had an idea, i choosed randomly a process and then put it in onother COMM and the reste stills in MPI_COMM_WORLD, and then i applicated MPI_Abort(COMM,0)

the idea seemed to work but when i tried it, it showed me error

here's the sample code i've did to kill process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int size, rank;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

MPI_Comm  comm1;
MPI_Group group1, grp_world;

MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &grp_world);
int *ranks = malloc((size-1) * sizeof(rank));
int rand_rank;
srand (time(NULL));
rand_rank = rand()%(size-1)+1;
printf("%d\n",rand_rank);

MPI_Group_incl(grp_world, 1, &rand_rank, &group1);
MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, group1, &comm1);

if (rank==0) {
printf("the total number of process before killing %d is %d",  rand_rank,size);
MPI_Abort(comm1,911);
printf("the total number of process after killing %d is %d", rand_rank,size);
```

}

```
MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
```

}

and the results :

```
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank -2 in communicator MPI_COMM_NULL 
with errorcode 911.
```

So if anyone guys have an idea how to achieve this, i've tried everything , Thankyou

Comment: Error says `comm1` is null: `MPI_COMM_NULL`. By the way, you cannot abort a single MPI rank and expect others to continue running. The MPI runtime would know and kill all the processes. Try to put it in a long sleep to mimic failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPI kill unwanted processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774968/mpi-kill-unwanted-processes)